# What does "get all wrong" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

> 90+4: Pogba looks to spread the play for Sancho, but he **gets his pass all wrong** as the ball bounces away from the former Borussia Dortmund man and out for a goal kick.

Answer (score 1):

It means he made a serious mistake when he executed the pass. As a result the ball didn't go where it should have.